# "Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryFailedException: Unauthorized" when creating a DiscoveryClient object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365, adal

I've got an ASP.Net MVC 5 web application that is attempting to integrate with Office 365/Azure AD.

The application successfully allows Sign In/Out, as well as successfully delegates permission for Graph API calls and calls to a separate Web API of mine which auths against Azure AD. So, something is working.

However, when trying to create a DiscoveryClient object, I am getting the `Unauthorised` ErrorCode in a DiscoveryFailedException.

The offending method:

```
public static async Task<SharePointClient> CreateSharePointClientAsync(string capability)
{
    var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext(OfficeSettings.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(signInUserId));
    var credential = new ClientCredential(OfficeSettings.ClientId, OfficeSettings.ClientSecret);
    var userIdent = new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

    try
    {
        DiscoveryClient discoClient = new DiscoveryClient("https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/",
             async () =>
             {
                 var authResult = await ctx.AcquireTokenAsync("https://api.office.com/discovery/",
                                                              credential);
                 return authResult.AccessToken;
             });

        var capabilityResult = await discoClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capability);
        return new SharePointClient(capabilityResult.ServiceEndpointUri,
            async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await ctx.AcquireTokenAsync(capabilityResult.ServiceResourceId,
                                                              credential);
                return authResult.AccessToken;
            });
    }
    catch (AdalException ex)
    {
        if (ex.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
        {
            ctx.TokenCache.Clear();
            throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The error occurs at the call to `ctx.AcquireTokenAsync` in the lambda of the DiscoveryClient instantiation.

As above, the application can sign in users, so the ClientId/Secret must be correct and I also believe the permissions required for this are similar to what is required to use the Discovery Service.

I've also tried to skip the discovery step and just hard-code the ResourceId for the Sharepoint client to see if I can leave it like this for the time being; however, I'm also getting some permission errors here, too, despite the appropriate permissions being granted for the application in the AAD management page.

I'm at a complete loss; running the example application from [O365-ASPNETMVC-Start](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start) works as you'd expect using the same credentials to sign in to Office 365.
To try and pinpoint the issue, the (what I believe to be the relevant) code is now practically identical to the (working) example, with still no luck.

If any other code would be useful in solving the issue, I'll happily share.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Hey did you solve this issue, I am currently having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To start, I haven't tried to alter the O365-ASPNETMVC-Start sample to work with the unified API endpoint (Graph API). While I haven't tried what you're doing, I'd expect the discovery calls to not work when targeting the unified API. The discoveryClient was useful when you needed to discover the endpoint. Since there is only one endpoint, there is no need to discover it. I suggest you take a look at [Office 365 unified API overview (preview)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-overview) to get some more background.

I suggest you take a look at the 
[Office 365 Profile sample for Windows](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Win-Profile) as it uses the unified endpoint. It uses the unified API client library that you'll want to use if targeting the unified endpoint.

Do note that the unified API is in preview. The APIs used by the O365-ASPNETMVC-Start sample are what is currently endorsed for production use.

Please tag your question with the [Office365] tag so that other interested people can see your question.

With regards,

Comment: Thanks for the help; admittedly, I had misunderstood what the Graph API was for, but I am now enlightened!
However, I'm still having the same issues while dragging some of this stuff about, trying to isolate the cause. I think the unified API may be a red herring? Reason being, I've only been using it for retrieving user profile information (my initial misunderstanding being that it was a "User Graph" API, doh) outside of the main authorisation flow.
My only remaining reference to the Unified API, appears in the O365-ASPNETMVC-Start example also (Startup.Auth.cs, Line 59).

Comment: Ok, I'm working round the issue now by using `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` in place, which is working.
No idea where my actual issue lies now, given the supporting code works in the sample project. Possibly something to do with the project template in VS 2013 doing something I'm not expecting, there seems to be additional WIF stuff that isn't present in the O365 sample.

Comment: You may want to checkout these samples as well. https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-SingleTenant, https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant.

Comment: @Dean Becker how we can get authorization code without redirecting user?